# How to open a URL in Java from a Swing app?

Tags: java, swing, url

I made this code with GUI to open URL. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextFieldExample
{  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
        JFrame f= new JFrame("TextField Example");  
        JTextField turl;  
        turl=new JTextField();  
        turl.setBounds(100,50, 300,50);  

        Font font = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD,20);
        turl.setFont(font);
        String url=turl.getText(); 

        JButton b1=new JButton(new ImageIcon("button.png"));  
        b1.setBounds(138,100,230,60); 

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                    URI oURL = new URI(url);
                    desktop.browse(oURL);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(turl); 
        f.setSize(500,300);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);//56 
    }  
}
```

But when I run this and enter a URL, it is opening the file explorer. Can someone find a solution?

Comment: *It is opening the file explorer* - and what do you want to happen? And what text do you enter in your text field?

Comment: Please learn how to format your code correctly. If it was correctly formatted before you copied it, you should look at the preview before submitting your question to make sure it looks good. There is no excuse for posting something which is that difficult to read.

Comment: You're using the [browse method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) which is built to do exactly what you describe is happening. If you're expecting something else, then I advise doing more research on the tools to make sure you're using the right ones.

Comment: You get the `url` in the `main` method before the UI has even been displayed, and then you don't get it in your `actionPerformed` method, so the URL will always be the empty string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you [edit] a question, be sure to use the `Edit` link below it to do so. That way you will not wipe out the edits of others which improve it (as happened here). As it happens, the only substantive change to the original was *"Please help me. I am new to java. But I know python. But I am Studying java because its good for internet. If you find a solution please say."*. None of that should be in a question in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Here's the revised GUI I created.  The font you chose for the `JTextField` leads to a pretty wide `JTextField`.

[image: TextField Example]

The first thing I did was to start the Swing GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the `JPanel`.  Even though you can place Swing components directly on a `JFrame`, it's wiser to create one or more `JPanels` to place on the `JFrame`.

The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for all my Swing applications.

The `JFrame` has a default [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), which I used. I used a `BorderLayout` for the `JPanel` I created to hold the `JTextField` and the `JButton`.

I moved the ActionListener into its own class.  Most Swing applications require multiple classes, so you might as well get used to the idea now.

Here's the complete, runnable code.  I made the URLListener class an inner class so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextFieldExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextFieldExample());
    }
    
    private JTextField urlTextField;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TextField Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        f.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        urlTextField = new JTextField(40);
        Font font = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 20);
        urlTextField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(urlTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Submit URL");
        b1.addActionListener(new URLListener());
        panel.add(b1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        return panel;
                
    }
    
    public class URLListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
                URI oURL = new URI(urlTextField.getText().trim());
                desktop.browse(oURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `URI oURL = new URI(urlTextField.getText().trim());` That's really the core of the solution. I.E. `// Get the text when the action is performed.`. Could that inner class be moved to the top of the source code, and a comment added to highlight it? It'd be great if the solution was there at the top where it could be seen without scrolling.

Comment: Noting you made an edit to implore people to help, I am amazed you made that edit without making any comment on the single answer which offered some. Is this answer not solving the problem? Why not?